# Scraping web data with Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

Below is a portion of the code i have written to scrape the bikesales.com.au website for details of bikes for sales (The full code is [here](https://github.com/beaubellamy/BikeSalesScraper)). This finds all the 'href' attributes on each search page and tries to request the html for each href corresponding to each bike for sale. My code works correctly, however I had to add some retry attempts with exponential backoff to avoid the following error:

```
ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None)
```

**The code works correctly**, however I would like to avoid the backoff approach if possible.

```
from requests import get
from requests.exceptions import RequestException
from contextlib import closing
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_html_content(url, multiplier=1):
    """
    Retrieve the contents of the url.
    """
    # Be a responisble scraper.
    # The multiplier is used to exponentially increase the delay when there are several attempts at connecting to the url
    time.sleep(2*multiplier)

    # Get the html from the url
    try:
        with closing(get(url)) as resp:
            content_type = resp.headers['Content-Type'].lower()
            if is_good_response(resp):
                return resp.content
            else:
                # Unable to get the url response
                return None

    except RequestException as e:
        print("Error during requests to {0} : {1}".format(url, str(e)))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    baseUrl = 'https://www.bikesales.com.au/'
    url = 'https://www.bikesales.com.au/bikes/?q=Service%3D%5BBikesales%5D'

    content = get_html_content(url)
    html = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
    BikeList = html.findAll("a", {"class": "item-link-container"})

    # Cycle through the list of bikes on each search page.
    for bike in BikeList:

        # Get the URL for each bike.
        individualBikeURL = bike.attrs['href']
        BikeContent = get_html_content(baseUrl+individualBikeURL)

        # Reset the miltipler for each new url
        multiplier = 1

        ## occasionally the connection is lost, so try again.
        ## Im not sure why the connection is lost, i might be that the site is trying to guard against scraping software.

        # If initial attempt to connect to the url was unsuccessful, try again with an increasing delay
        while (BikeContent == None):
            # Limit the exponential delay to 16x
            if (multiplier < 16):
                multiplier *= 2
            BikeContent = get_html_content(baseUrl+individualBikeURL,multiplier)
```

My question is, Is there something that i am missing in the implementation of the request? or, is this just a result of the site denying scraping tools?

Comment: I would be interested to know if this code will work on any website or just a specific website?

Comment: I've edited the question to more clearly indicate that the code functions. Please confirm that my edit was correct.

Comment: Could you include the code for `is_good_response`?

Comment: @Peilonrayz https://github.com/beaubellamy/BikeSalesScraper/blob/master/BikeSalesScraper/BikeSalesScraper.py#L18-L25

Comment: @MathiasEttinger Thank you, unfortunately it still has licencing issues. And so we wouldn't be able to include it in an answer.

Comment: @Malachi: I've used the same code to scrape one other website 'skiresort.info' without any issues.

Comment: @Dannno, your edits were a help and correct. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. I assume `is_good_response` is just checking for a 200 response code.
2. Merge `is_good_response`, `get_html_content` and the insides of your for-loop in your main together.

This makes the main code:

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

if __name__ == '__main__':
    baseUrl = 'https://www.bikesales.com.au/'
    url = 'https://www.bikesales.com.au/bikes/?q=Service%3D%5BBikesales%5D'

    content = get_html_content(url)
    html = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
    BikeList = html.findAll("a", {"class": "item-link-container"})

    for bike in bike_list:
        individualBikeURL = bike.attrs['href']
        bike_content = get_bike(baseUrl+individualBikeURL)
```

Where we will be focusing on:

```
def get_bike(url):
    multiplier = 1
    while (BikeContent == None):
        time.sleep(2*multiplier)
        try:
            with closing(get(url)) as resp:
                content_type = resp.headers['Content-Type'].lower()
                if 200 <= resp.status_code < 300:
                    return resp.content
        except RequestException as e:
            print("Error during requests to {0} : {1}".format(url, str(e)))
        if (multiplier < 16):
            multiplier *= 2
    return None
```

1. Allow a retry argument. Retry should also act differently on different values:

   - None - Don't retry.
   - -1 - Retry infinatly.
   - n - Retry until \$2^n\$.
   - iterator - loop through for the delays

   We can also add another function to work the same way your previous code did.
2. You shouldn't need to use `contextlib.closing`, as `Response.close` "[should not normally need to be called explicitly.](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response.close)"
3. You don't need `content_type` in `get_bike`.
4. You should use `*args` and `**kwargs` so you can use `requests.get`s arguments if you ever need to.
5. You can allow this to work with `post` and other request methods if you take the method as a parameter.

```
import itertools
import collections.abc

import requests.exceptions


def request(method, retry=None, *args, **kwargs):
    if retry is None:
        retry = iter()
    elif retry == -1:
        retry = (2**i for i in itertools.count())
    elif isinstance(retry, int):
        retry = (2**i for i in range(retry))
    elif isinstance(retry, collections.abc.Iterable):
        pass
    else:
        raise ValueError('Unknown retry {retry}'.format(retry=retry))

    for sleep in itertools.chain([0], retry):
        if sleep:
            time.sleep(sleep)
        try:
            resp = method(*args, **kwargs)
            if 200 <= resp.status_code < 300:
                return resp.content
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            print('Error during requests to {0} : {1}'.format(url, str(e)))
    return None


def bike_retrys():
    for i in range(5):
        yield 2**i
    while True:
        yield 16
```

---

To improve the rest of the code:

1. Use snake case.
2. Constants should be in upper snake case.
3. Use the above code.
4. Use `import requests`, rather than `from requests import get`.
5. You can make a little helper function to call `request`, so usage is cleaner.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_bike(*args, **kwargs):
    return request(requests.get, bike_retrys(), *args, **kwargs)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    BASE_URL = 'https://www.bikesales.com.au/'
    url = 'https://www.bikesales.com.au/bikes/?q=Service%3D%5BBikesales%5D'

    content = get_bike(url)
    html = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
    bike_list = html.findAll("a", {"class": "item-link-container"})

    for bike in bike_list:
        bike_content = get_bike(BASE_URL + bike.attrs['href'])
```

Comment: `if 200 <= resp.status_code < 300` => `if resp.ok`?

Comment: @MathiasEttinger I didn't know [`resp.ok`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response.ok) was a thing. However, from the documentation, it is the same as `200 <= resp.status_code < 400`.

Comment: Right, but since `allow_redirects=False` is not used here, all 3xx are converted to the final element.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger I'll admit I don't know much about 3xx. From what you put it'd be better to use it whether we use `allow_redirects` or not. I'll edit my answer in a bit, or you can if you want.